# Rare NullPointerException in GoogleApiClient using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-api-client, google-api-java-client

**I am using GoogleApiClient to login users using their Google account.** Basically, I am using Firebase Auth with Google sign in.

**But I am getting this crash on some devices every single day**. When I test on some of my own devices (OnePlus 3, Nexus 5X, Moto G, etc) I never see this crash.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toLowerCase(java.util.Locale)' on a null object reference
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamy.zzd(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamv.n(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamv.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamv$2.run(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

This is what I am doing to instantiate the GoogleApiClient. I don't see the crash in normal situations but in some devices I am seeing this. Here is what I am doing in code,

```
String mClientId = parcel.getProviderExtra().getString(CLIENT_ID_KEY);
GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions;

googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(mClientId)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(App.getContext())
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, googleSignInOptions)
                .build();

mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

What am I doing wrong here? My best bet is, `App.getContext()` which gives the application context to instantiate the client. Can this be the problem?

I can use the activity context, but using that leads to a memory leak. What is the problem here and how can it be solved?

This is creating a very poor experience to some users who get a crash just after opening the app and trying to sing in.

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: Have you tryed to use `getApplicationContext()` method in stead of `App.getContext()`? Is this happening also if you use `.requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))`?

Comment: @AlexMamo tried `getApplicationContext`  with no luck

Comment: @GiruBhai, is you stack trace exactly the same? What version of `com.google.android.gms` do you compile against?

Comment: @SergGr Thanks to reply, stacktrace is in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43864774/googlesigninoptions-googleapiclient-bind-service-serviceconnection-crash and using latest `10.2.1`

Comment: Have you tryed to use `enableAutoManage` on `googleApiClient`?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes, Please check my original question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43864774/googlesigninoptions-googleapiclient-bind-service-serviceconnection-crash.

Comment: This could be another manifestation of the [bug](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/291), also reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42362024/firebase-remote-config-nullpointerexception-on-map-keyset)

Answer (score 1):

Hello You can try this code this is a working code in my project
 first initialize google api client in on create

```
public void initGPlus() {
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
}
```

and on the button click call another function

```
 Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

In On Activity result just got your response and handle that result in a function

```
if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
```

implement this interface in your activity

```
 implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
```

Comment: I already did as you suggest but it crashed at `mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this) `

Comment: You may see in my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43864774/googlesigninoptions-googleapiclient-bind-service-serviceconnection-crash

Comment: if your in starting of your app you can upload it on git may be i can help in better way

Comment: I did exactly as https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/signin/SignInActivity.java

Comment: issue occur in Redmi devices only.

Comment: I had checked the code its working fine but i dont have mi device to test

Comment: check that other app which are having google login working on that phone

Comment: so its not your code issue its a phone issue Your app will work fine

Comment: But Now A days most users having MI Devices.

Answer (score -1):

While checking for Google Play services would be good, I think this may be due to a device having an old version of Google Play services.but that's not a great error regardless.

Comment: On Device, Google Play services is up-to-date.